# How do I fix this error, cant write another file in C

Tags: c, visual-studio

So I'm trying to get this code to work and it's giving me an error. I've tried to search it up but couldn't find anything to get it to work.

Error (active)  E0513   a value of type "errno_t" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "FILE *"
I get that error and this one

Error   C2440   '=': cannot convert from 'errno_t' to 'FILE *'  ch11Program

Any ideas what to do here?

```
FILE *cfPtr;

cfPtr = fopen_s(&cfPtr,"client.txt", "w");
if ( cfPtr == NULL) {
    puts("File could not be opened");
}
else {
    puts("Enter the account, name, and balance.");
    puts("Enter E0F to end input.");
    printf("%s", "? ");

    unsigned int account;
    char name[30];
    double balance;

    scanf_s("%d%29s%lf", &account, name, &balance);

    while (!feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance);
        printf("%s", "? ");
        scanf_s("%d%29s%lf", &account, name, &balance);
    }
    fclose(cfPtr);
}
```

Comment: `fopen_s` returns an `errno_t` and you are assigning it to `cfPtr`, which is type `FILE *`. Read the document describing [`fopen_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/z5hh6ee9(v%3Dvs.140)).

Comment: -1. This question should be closed, the problem is with reading documentation and it is unlikely to help someone in the future.

Comment: Please note that Microsoft's [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2017) requires a **length argument** for `%s` and `%c` format spec types, and the compiler does issue a warning. Also please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign fopen_s() to cfPtr because they are of different types. Instead try this:

```
FILE *cfPtr;
errno_t err;

err = fopen_s(&cfPtr,"client.txt", "w");
if ( err == NULL) {
    puts("File could not be opened");
}
else {
puts("Enter the account, name, and balance.");
puts("Enter E0F to end input.");
printf("%s", "? ");

unsigned int account;
char name[30];
double balance;

scanf_s("%d%29s%lf", &account, name, &balance);

while (!feof(stdin)) {
    fprintf(cfPtr, "%d %s %.2f\n", account, name, balance);
    printf("%s", "? ");
    scanf_s("%d%29s%lf", &account, name, &balance);
}
fclose(cfPtr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but do you have any idea why this program isn't creating a file now?